# SAMPLE javaclient is working , from JAVA-APPLICATION saying unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, tls1.2

Below sample javaclient is working.. connecting to server and getting output[Response Code : 200]

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.io.*;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

public class HttpsClient{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        new HttpsClient().testIt();
   }

   private void testIt(){


String https_url = "https://sampleserver.net:443/webapp/connect.dll?Connect&time=2208282020&serial=46010&value=758.24";

      URL url;
      try {

         url = new URL(https_url);
         HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

         //dumpl all cert info
         print_https_cert(con);

         //dump all the content
         print_content(con);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   private void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con){

    if(con!=null){

      try {

    System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
    System.out.println("\n");

    Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
    for(Certificate cert : certs){
       System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
       System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
       System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : "
                                    + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
       System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : "
                                    + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
       System.out.println("\n");
    }

    } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     }

   }

   private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con){
    if(con!=null){

    try {

       System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
       BufferedReader br =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

       String input;

       while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
          System.out.println(input);
       }
       br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

       }

   }

}
```

Output

```
Response Code : 200
Cipher Suite : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA


Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 31005469
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509


Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 16813553
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509


Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 5605913
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509
```

executed from jdk7 and jdk8....by changing path.[Response Code : 200]

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin:$PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/javac HttpsClient.java
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java -classpath . -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts HttpsClient > output.txt
```

When call from java-application , which uses above jdk7 as its runtime folder ..saying below exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:308)
    at com.ph.linkshared.port.socket.base.client.HttpGetThread.runThread(HttpGetThread.java:144)
    at com.ph.linkshared.port.socket.base.client.HttpGetThread.run(HttpGetThread.java:77)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 20 more
```

1. Any thoughts on why failing from application , with certs issue?
2. -Djavax.net.debug=all /  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data  /  -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,handshake,data,trustmanager  from javaClient and shows Response code "200"
3. root and intermediate certs added to jdk via keytool
4. Cipher Suite : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  will support both jdk7 and jdk8?

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts on why failing from application , with certs issue?

Either the application is using a truststore other than the default (either a different one to start with, or modifying it), or it is getting different cert(s) from the server, perhaps by connecting to a different host than you expected, perhaps by going through a proxy of some kind, or perhaps by changing parameters on the connection which causes the (same) server to respond differently, e.g. disabling SNI where you didn't or restricting or reordering ciphersuites so as to get a different keyexchange.

Try running the *app* (i.e. the failure case) with `javax.net.debug=ssl[:trustmanager:handshake]` (those detail categories are already on by default and thus not needed for 7 and 8 except the very recent 8u261 and maybe one of the paid 7 updates, and 9 and 10, but do need to be specified for 11 up and 8u261). Look at the certs loaded by the trustmanager to see whether they include the ones you need, and look at the cert chain received from the server to see whether it is what you expected or different, and in particular if it doesn't match what was loaded in the trustmanager.

PS: printing `cert.getType()` is useless; JSSE *only* supports X.509 certs in TLS. (Technically RFCs for other certs exist, but they are almost never implemented or used.) Printing `cert.hashCode()` gives an internal object identifier that is not useful for anything except determining if two objects are the same object, which will never be the case for certs received from a server. Printing `cert.getPublicKey().getFormat()` is utterly useless because *all* JCE publickeys have format X.509; see [the javadoc for java.security.Key.getFormat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getFormat--). Also, the algorithm for the leaf cert is determined by the ciphersuite; in principle the algorithms for CA cert(s) could differ but they rarely do, and in any case they aren't related in any way to your problem.

What *might* help is `((X509Certificate)cert).getSubjectX500Principal()` and `.getIssuerX500Principal()` and maybe validity (`.getNotBefore()` and `.getNotAfter()`) and `.getBasicConstraints()` and `.getKeyUsage()`. But the debug log has this same info already, and in consistent form.

Comment: will check on proxy , wondering is javaClient get 200 response with same cacerts(jdk7) , this was working with https till march 2020 , after new certs installed -stopped working , change made in certs is COMODO to Sectigo, will include our-network-resource and host-network-resource to see where request is failing., will add javax.net.debug=ssl[:trustmanager:handshake] in app to get more debug details.